# How to make jQuery code work when page loads using lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, conditional-statements, lazy-loading

I have a some div s, for example like facebook posts, and posts are loading using lazy load 6 posts at a time.
inside each post there are comments there are comments, I have added a jQuery function for the comments to show/ hide extra characters in comments as seen below in my jQuery code.

the problem is code is working for first 6 posts, 
but when new the posts loading using lazy load my code does not works,
is it possible to make this code work for all posts.

---

> jQuery Code

```
let certainAmount = 5;
const $container = $('.main');

$container.each(function(){
  let $this = $(this);

  console.log($this.find('> *').length);

  if(($this.find('> *').length) > (certainAmount - 1) ) {
    //Selected and do something.
            i=0;
        $.each($('.main img'), function (index, value) {             
            i++;
            console.log('um inside'+i);
            $('.main img').css('display','block');
            $('.main img').css('float','left');
            $('.main img:nth-child(10)').nextAll().css('display','none');    

        });
     $('.main').has('>img:nth-child(5)').append("<a class='show-more'>See More</a>");
  }
});
```

---

```
<div class="main">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
<div class="main">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
     <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
<div class="main">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
<div class="main">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
<div class="main">
   <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">  <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/htc/122/grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f601.png">
</div>
```

Comment: `'>img:nth-child(5)` only at the first 5 child?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes, it means display only first 5 children or charactors of all comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code which you've written is on page load, so the elements which are ready when the document is loaded it is working fine.

To work as expected, for the lazy load of the components, you need to instantiate the same method while you are loading the components using lazy load.